# sending message from one emulator to another through C2DM

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-c2dm

I have read the tutorial of C2DM from given link
[C2DM](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)

I have followed the steps and able to obtain registration ID , authenticaton token for my device .but I don't understand how the C2DM server will come to know to whom the message is to be delivered.
When I send the message it is received on the same device , but i want to send this to other emulator.so I want to know that for this whether I have to make another applicatin with the same content or I can launch two emulators from the same appliaction and send messages from one to another .

Now my main question is :
when I give the registration Id And token it's actually of the sender's or the receiver's

Answer (score 0):

> whether I have to make another applicatin with the same content or I can launch two emulators from the same appliaction and send messages from one to another .

You should be able to just make one application and use two different emulators.

> Now my main question is : when I give the registration Id And token it's actually of the sender's or the receiver's

Let me see if I understand you correctly here. You want to send a message from one device to the other right? Well you can't contact the other device directly. The best you can do is have the sending device post a message to the server with the id of the device you want to send it to. Note this probably won't be the other devices C2DM id (that could change for what ever reason), but rather some sort of name for which your sever will then have to resolve the C2DM id. Then, when the server gets the message, it figures out the id of the phone to send it to, sends a push to the recipient's phone, and then the recipients's phone downloads the data.

Does that make sense?

Comment: yes,can you pls provide me some sort of code or reference so that i can understand it well.....
One more thing i want to be clear about is , if i am not wrong both devices(emulators) are server and client as well.suppose A want to send msg to B ,then A is the server and B is the client and the vice versa.Am i right???Because the same application is running on both the devices.Then how both the devices send their Registration IDs to one another which is then used for sending messages ?

Comment: No, both applications are not servers. They're both clients. And like I said above, you shouldn't be messaging individual C2DM ids because those will change. I don't have any sample code because you've asked such a broad question. If you can focus your question I might be able to give you some sample code.

Comment: ok,let me be precise,I want to send a notification from one emulator to the another .How should I proceed?What is the best way you suggest?

Comment: That's no more precise or different than what you originally asked. Is there a specific portion of the algorithm I presented above that you don't understand?